# Check response code from jquery $.get()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I know this can be done with ajax, but I want to know how this could be done using the get() shortcut...

Given this:

```
$.get('someurl.com', function(data, statusText, xhr) {
        $('#sometag').html(data);
    });
```

How could I do error checking for anything that is NOT a 200? The api I am accessing returns 204s regularly if the request was valid but had no useful data to return.

Comment: You should be able to check it using `xhr.status`. Here's more information: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

Answer (score 3):

Fiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/smegha11/6xu3K/

You can use xhr.status property to check response code

```
$.get('someurl.com', function(data, statusText, xhr) {
    if(xhr.status==200)
    {
       $('#sometag').html(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using callback methods**

```
The Promise interface also allows jQuery's Ajax methods, including $.get(), to chain 
multiple .done(), .fail(), and .always() callbacks on a single request.
```

**Example**

```
$.get( "someurl.com", function() {
  Console.log( "success" );
}).done(function() {
    Console.log( "second success" );
  }).fail(function() {
    Console.log( "error" );
  }).always(function() {
    Console.log( "finished" );
  });
```

Check documentation for  [$get](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

**And here is which paramters each function is recieving**

```
jqXHR.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {});
An alternative construct to the success callback option, the .done() method replaces the deprecated jqXHR.success() method. Refer to deferred.done() for implementation details.

jqXHR.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {});
An alternative construct to the error callback option, the .fail() method replaces the deprecated .error() method. Refer to deferred.fail() for implementation details.

jqXHR.always(function( data|jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR|errorThrown ) { });
An alternative construct to the complete callback option, the .always() method replaces the deprecated .complete() method.

In response to a successful request, the function's arguments are the same as those of .done(): data, textStatus, and the jqXHR object. For failed requests the arguments are the same as those of .fail(): the jqXHR object, textStatus, and errorThrown. Refer to deferred.always() for implementation details.

jqXHR.then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {}, function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {});
Incorporates the functionality of the .done() and .fail() methods, allowing (as of jQuery 1.8) the underlying Promise to be manipulated. Refer to deferred.then() for implementation details.
```

Documentation for  [jqXHR objects](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR)